# Can anyone give jquery/javascript to limit no. of files to be uploaded in asp.net FileUpload control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using asp.net FileUpload control to upload multiple images. I want user will not upload more than 5 images. Can anyone give me solution in jquery/javascript?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in jquery FileUpload.

> ### limitMultiFileUploads
>
> To limit the number of files uploaded with one XHR request, set the following option to an integer greater than 0:
>
> - Type: integer
> - Default: undefined
> - Example: 3
>
> *Note: This option is ignored, if singleFileUploads is set to true or limitMultiFileUploadSize is set and the browser reports file sizes.*

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

Comment: I am using ASP:FileUpload not JQuery file upload